# Can you add a custom domain name for an Azure SQL connection, so not using xxxx.database.windows.net

Tags: sql-server, azure

When creating an Azure SQL Database you are supplied with a URL to connect with. 
xxxxxx.database.windows.net. I'd like to know if there is a way to use my own domain name i.e xxxx.mysite.com for that connection.

If I try that and CNAME the official Azure SQL URL I cannot connect to the database.

For web apps you can add custom domains names, but I'd like the same for Azure SQL. The far as I can see it cannot be done

Comment: Curious: why would you want to do that? Fwiw, I'd be extremely surprised if this was possible.

Comment: We have used DNS based SQL failover before and this way you can control the Live DB connection domain.

Comment: Fwiw, are you aware that SQL azure already has it's own failover? There are actually three SQL server instances behind the URL they give you.

Comment: The use case for us is to simplify migrating our Azure SQL database to a VM in AWS. Having a CNAME in front of Azure's DNS name allows us to change the underlying instance without having to change the connection strings for all our users, SSIS and SSRS packages.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to have a custom DNS entry for your SQL Azure servers, you should make a **CNAME** entry:

`liveDB.mydomain.com` to `abc123.database.windows.net`

`stageDB.mydomain.com` to `xyz456.database.windows.net`

For your connection strings, you are REQUIRED to use the format `login@servername`.

You still need the server name, because you need to login as `user@abc123`.

Check [this post for more details](http://geekswithblogs.net/dwdii/archive/2011/05/09/a-custom-dns-name-for-my-sql-azure-database-server.aspx)